# django , redis - the values getting flushed when redis restarts

Tags: python, django, redis, django-redis

I'm using

- Redis 2.2.12
- django-redis==3.8.4
- django 1.7

settings.py

```
CACHES = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/",

} }
```

python manage.py shell

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('key','value',300000)
cache.get('key')
>>value
```

but after `sudo service redis-server restart`

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.get('key')
>>NOTHING
```

with redis-cli same issue

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set key value
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "key"
```

but after `sudo service redis-server restart`

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
(empty list or set)
```

its flushing data when redis reload or restart

i Saw that i can manually call SAVE or BGSAVE to stay hot upon server restart. in redis-cli its working fine . How on django-redis ?

Comment: Do you realize that this is intented behaviour? Are you interested in configuring redis to persist data?

Comment: @Wtower . AOF persistence logs every write operation received by the server but its Slow right ? is there any alternative

Comment: It's not that slow. Only if you fsync every write. One second sync you will hardly notice. You can test it with `redis-benchmark`